# Import emails from Outlook to Gmail

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, csv

I have emails in my desktop Outlook and want to transfer them in Gmail (G Suite if it matters).

I exported a folder in a CSV file, however, cannot find a way to import them in Gmail. The solutions I can find online are for importing Contacts.

How to import emails from Outlook to Gmail?

The best is if I can preset a particular label for each file I import.

Comment: Have you tried: 1) [Export Outlook data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/export-or-backup-email-contacts-and-calendar-to-an-outlook-pst-file-14252b52-3075-4e9b-be4e-ff9ef1068f91) to a PST. 2) [Add your Gmail account](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-gmail-account-to-outlook-70191667-9c52-4581-990e-e30318c2c081) to Outlook. 3) [Import the PST](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-email-contacts-and-calendar-from-an-outlook-pst-file-431a8e9a-f99f-4d5f-ae48-ded54b3440ac) into your Gmail account without Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple solutions:

1. If your emails are in an online account too, like hotmail.com or outlook.com you can add the account to gmail, settings -> all settings -> Accounts and Import -> Check mail from other accounts, add your details there and gmail will connect and download all your emails into it.
2. If your emails are only on your outlook program, enable IMAP on gmail, settings -> all settings -> Forwarding and POP/IMAP -> IMAP Access, Once IMAP is enabled, add your gmail account to Outlook, and from there you can copy/move emails between different accounts by drag and drop

if you need help configuring gmail as IMAP into outlook, the information is here :
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?visit_id=637388227935420945-1410644768&hl=en&rd=1

Comment: Actually, I was able to import them via "Data Migration". May previous attempts failed because the field "Source Email" actually means "source account". I set it correctly with my account login and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing.